# How to get image data from database mysql in react native

Tags: php, json, reactjs, react-native, codeigniter

I have a problem, I am using backend with Codeigniter and upload the image to MySQL with varchar type.
This is the name of the image after I input:
[image]

and now I want to get that image to react native with fetch API, but how to get image from database to react native, because in MySQL just the name of the picture is saved? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save the file on the server's disk and filename name in your database. You'll have to know the location of your file so when you want to fetch it you'll have to build a full url to the file like `http://example-domain.com/uploads/filename.jpg` or you can save the full path in the database instead of just a filename. If you don't have a server to store the image you may consider saving the image blob into the database which I don't recommend.